# Is there a '#' operator in MaxJ? If so, what does it do?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, programming-languages

I saw this weird operator in a maxj file (maxeler technologies). DFEVar here is a stream.

This is the function:

```
private static FanoutLimiter<DFEVar> limitFanout(DFEVar v){
return new FanoutLimiter<DFEVar>(v, FANOUT_LIMIT);
}
```

And this is how its used:

```
FanoutLimiter<DFEVar> wrAddr = limitFanout(j # oddTile);
FanoutLimiter<DFEVar> rdAddr = limitFanout(j # ~oddTile);
```

What is this ‘#’ operand?

Comment: What is the file extension? I guess this is somehow a template, not a normal java source file.

Comment: That isn't legal Java. Java doesn't have operator overloading, `#` isn't a Java operator ([JLS-3.12. Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.12)), and there's no bit fiddling in a method call on an object type.

Comment: As you stated, it is **maxj** not **java**. It is just a custom language that looks like Java. You are just like mixing Java with JavaScript. I'm going to flag this as off-topic.

Comment: No I am sure that it is java. Let me share the source in a few minutes.

Comment: @glee8e you can examine this: http://www.st.ewi.tudelft.nl/~varbanescu/ASCI_A24.2k12/ASCI_A24_Day3_Session2.pdf it says: "MaxJ is an extension of Java for MaxCompiler"

Comment: Ok, that comparsion to JavaScript is wrong. But please consider this: C++ could once be considered an extension of C, and can C compiler compile C++ sources for you? Since MaxJ extends Java, it must contain something that Java doesn't have.

Comment: @glee8e in that case is it ok to change java in the title with maxj? I really need an answer.

Comment: Of course you can, but I'm afraid you won't gt an anwser unless you are very lucky... There is no tag for maxj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#` operator in MaxJ is doing concatenation.